# Static files not loading (Django 1.11)

Tags: python, django

I am trying to set up a development version of a Django Rest (1.11) application on a mac.

I have run the `python manage.py collectstatic` command and this resulted in the files being copied into a 'static' folder.

However when I run the application (`python manage.py runserver`) none of the static files load in the browser (no css). The Network tab shows the status of the static files as 404.

My settings.py file has the following:

`STATIC_URL = '/static/' 
STATIC_ROOT = BASE_DIR + '/abba_rest/static/'`

Appreciate any advice on how to debug this issue.

Comment: Are you getting 404? Share your urls.py inside project directory.

Comment: They are probably not found, which means your path would be wrong.

Comment: How did you reference these static files ?

Comment: you should do {% static 'filename' %} and your static files should be in `/abba_rest/static/` in root of project

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the static files to load by using the --insecure flag when starting the server;

```
python manage.py runserver --insecure
```